# My doc2vec library cannot load DocvecsArray.is there a solution.python code

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word2vec, doc2vec

it shows  Can't get attribute 'DocvecsArray' on <module 'gensim.models.doc2vec' from 'C:\Users\aysha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\doc2vec.py'> in anaconda prompt while compiling my code.What should i do to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

`DocvecsArray` is a long-obsolete class name from older versions of Gensim.

Are you trying to load an old model into a Python environment with a current Gensim? If so, do you know from which version of Gensim the model was saved (even approximately, or by date)?

It may be possible to bring an old model forward, but it may require one or more interim steps, where the model is loaded into an older version of Gensim, that can still read, convert, & then re-save (in a newer format) the old model.

Comment: yes,but i do not know which model it is. Is there a way?The codes are around 10 months old...or as it is last  updated.

Comment: I put tips for loading an older model or the apparent vintage of your files in an answer to your separate question on the same topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71101966/run-model-that-need-gensim-older-vesion/71107673#71107673